# How to stop "Update Background Files"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, resharper

I keep seeing a progress bar at the bottom right of my Visual Studio 2015 environment that constantly appears each time I'm typing that says "Update  background files". I've narrowed it down to being related to Resharper, but I can't figure out why this happens or how to turn it off! I've  tried to clean all caches but it doesn't help.
The process is very slow and annoying.  Anyone know how to stop this from happening?  I'm using the latest version of Resharper v9.0.1 on Visual Studio 2015.

Thank you

Comment: Resharper has to update files in the background *because* you cleaned the caches! Now it has to reprocess all files, otherwise it won't be able to perform solution-wide analysis. Close that if you have to.

Comment: I'm afraid that just how the product (Resharper) works. Because of that it requires a machine with a bit of power. Make sure it has decent RAM (8GB or more) and I highly recommend using a solid state drive (SSD).

Comment: You can put the caches on an SSD or even a RAM drive, by changing the cache location from Resharper's options

Comment: I using SSD ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ReSharper 9.0.1 does not support the latest builds of Visual Studio 2015 (AFAIK it supports first builds of [VS2015 Preview](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2014/12/05/resharper-9-is-released-along-with-dottrace-6-dotcover-3-dotmemory-4-2-and-dotpeek-1-3/)). So you need to install at least ReSharper 9.2 to support VS2015 RTM or ReSharper 2016.2 to supports VS2015 Update 3.